# oracle xmlexists with variable path

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, xmltype, oracle-xml-db

I have a table tsk with 2 columns : a task id in number, and a task scope in XMLTYPE which can be like :

```
<scope>
    <siteCode>2</siteCode>
    <supplierCode>1111</supplierCode>
    <contractCode>464</contractCode>
    <orderNumber>85235478</orderNumber>
</scope>
```

But the elements under the tag  may vary from one record to another

I need to select task ids which match some conditions in the scope.
For example :

```
select tskid
from tsk t 
where xmlexists('$a/scope[siteCode = 2 and supplierCode = 111]' passing t.tskscope as "a");
```

As the scope may vary, I have a PL/SQL function taking a xml path p_xmlpath to look for, in varchar2 type.
So for example, p_xmlpath will be :

```
p_xmlpath := 'scope[siteCode = 2 and supplierCode = 1111]';
```

Then I want to run the query with XMLEXISTS to find the matching records.
I thought to do it with bind variables in the following way :

```
select tskid
from tsk t 
where xmlexists('$a/$b' passing t.tskscope as "a", p_xmlpath as "b" );
```

By doing this, the query returns all records, without taking the condition with xmlexists.

Does someone know how to manage this, i.e. having a variable path to give to XMLEXISTS ?

Additional info : until now, I used the function existsNode and the following query was doing the job correctly:

```
select tskid
from tsk t 
where existsnode(t.tskscope, p_xmlpath) = 1;
```

But on one hand existsNode is deprecated and on the other I noticed that in my situation the function xmlexists was noticeably faster than existsNode, that's why I would to switch to xmlexists.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can; it seems to only allow the search values to be variables, not the whole search condition.

As a workaround you could build the XPath at runtome with `replace()`:

```
select tskid
from tsk t 
where xmlexists(replace('$a/$b', '$b', p_xmlpath) passing t.tskscope as "a");
```

or build the XPath string as a variable if you'd rather not have a replace in there, and include the `$a/` part:

```
p_xmlpath := '$a/' || p_xmlpath;

select tskid
from tsk t 
where xmlexists(p_xmlpath passing t.tskscope as "a");
```

Comment: Thanks ! I tried the solution with defining the whole path as a variable and it gives me the correct results. Unfortunately, the query is 200 times longer than if I run it with the same path in a literal string, I don't why ...